# Ignite report IgniteOutOfMemoryException: Out of memory in data region

Tags: ignite

I build a cache cluster based on apache ignite core jar 2.7.0, the server process exited with the OOM error:

```
org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.error JVM will be halted immediately due to the failure: [failureCtx=FailureContext [type=CRITICAL_ERROR, err=class o.a.i.i.mem.IgniteOutOfMemoryException: Out of memory in data region [name=keywordRegion, initSize=256.0 MiB, maxSize=8.0 GiB, persistenceEnabled=false] Try the following:
  ^-- Increase maximum off-heap memory size (DataRegionConfiguration.maxSize)
  ^-- Enable Ignite persistence (DataRegionConfiguration.persistenceEnabled)
  ^-- Enable eviction or expiration policies]]
```

the region is configured as:

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
    <property name="name" value="keywordRegion"/>
    <property name="maxSize" value="#{1024L * 1024 * 1024 * 8}"/>
    <property name="pageEvictionMode" value="RANDOM_2_LRU"/>
    <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

about the given 3 suggestions in the error log:

1. I want to limit the cache size to 8g;
2. I only want to use memory cache;
3. PageEvictionMode is set to RANDOM_2_LRU;

and I tested some cases, when the cache values are the same size, eviction works well, when they are in random size, the OOM is caused.
What is the matter? is it wrong configured? Thanks.

edited:
This is my test, the max region size is set to 120M, the OOM occured around 200th loop, when the mega declared line is moved to the front of the for loop, ignite works well.

```
IgniteCache<String, Object> keywordCache = ignite.getOrCreateCache("keyword");
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
        int mega = new Random().nextInt(3) + 1;
        keywordCache.put(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), new byte[mega * 1024 * 1024]);
        System.out.println("current:"+i);
    }
```

Comment: Is there any reproducer that you can share? I tried to start node with your configuration and put data in while loop with different sizes(from 1 to 1024 bytes), but it works without any issues

Comment: hi, i added the test case to the end of the question, I run the tests many times, it can produce the same ignite oom 100%.

Answer (score 3):

These objects are bigger than default property for emptyPagesPoolSize in EvictionPolicy, so, it could lead to such behavior. You can add this line to the DataRegionConfiguration:

```
<property name="emptyPagesPoolSize" value="5000"/>
```

I've checked your reproducer and it works after applying this property.

Comment: yes, it indeed works for that case, but it failed when the mega increased(e.g. set the mega random in 1-10), and my value could even larger than 40M, could you please explain what is the reasonable relation between emptyPagesPoolSize and max cache value?

Comment: emptyPagesPoolSize * pageSize should be at least more than the biggest object size that will be stored in the heap. Default pageSize is 4kb, so, for 40m emptyPagesPoolSize should be at least 10000, but I would recommend to use a bigger value, i.e. 20000

Comment: Evgenii, thanks for your help, but it may be difficult to predict the max size, 20000 is not a safe value, and when the emptyPagesPoolSize set to 20000, cache value random in 1-50m, the put method takes seconds to return, RANDOM_LRU works slightly better than RANDOM_2_LRU, jstack shows that it is struggling to evictDataPage, it seems that ignite is designed to store small values and not fit to my use case, right?

Comment: In our case, we haven't configured any EvictionPolicy, still we got Out of memory in data region (maxSize=68.0 GiB) in our production and Ignite got stopped. Does it mean we have loaded 68 GB data into Ignite? Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: Yes, it means that you have loaded more data that you allocated for the data region. You can use memory metrics to understand the current memory usage: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/memory-metrics